# How to find missing date and shift in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

There are three columns in my MySQL table:

```
id   | date       | shift  
-----+------------+---------
52   | 2017-01-01 | 1
51   | 2017-01-01 | 2
51   | 2017-01-01 | 3
51   | 2017-01-02 | 1
51   | 2017-01-02 | 3
51   | 2017-01-03 | 1
51   | 2017-01-03 | 2
51   | 2017-01-05 | 1
51   | 2017-01-05 | 2
51   | 2017-01-05 | 3
```

In this table two shifts are missing; 2nd shift of `2017-01-02`, and 3rd shift of `2017-01-03`. and 2017-01-04 date are full missed So how can I find this with a MySQL query?
and i want condition that find where id='51'
then result is 1st shift is also missing in `2017-01-01`
and also find that missed 27 days and show 27 dates.
please help me.

Comment: include what you have started the php and query

Comment: SQL doesn't help you here. It can extract data from the database but only the data that **already is** in the database.

Comment: How do you found those records are missing?, is there any specification/ convention about each date should have 3 shift or there is another table for shifts?

Comment: @Beginner i use only mysql not php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way is by making all acceptable rows then filter current rows like this:

```
select *
from (
    select `date`
    from `yourTable`
    group by `date`) as `td`     -- gathering unique data
cross join (
    select 1 `shift`
    union all select 2
    union all select 3) as `ts`  -- generating a source for shifts
-- filtering those are not exists in current rows
where not exists (
    select 1 from `yourTable` as `ti`
    where `ti`.`date` = `td`.`date` and `ti`.`shift` = `ts`.`shift`);
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16fdff/1)

---

**Update :**

Answer to your question in comments can be this:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from (
      select `id`, `date`          -- <= added `id`
      from `yourTable`
      group by `id`, `date`) as `td`     -- gathering unique data <= added `id`
  cross join (
      select 1 `shift`
      union all select 2
      union all select 3) as `ts`  -- generating a source for shifts
  where not exists (
      select 1 from `yourTable` as `ti`
      -- filtering those are not exists in current rows
      where `ti`.`date` = `td`.`date` 
        and `ti`.`id` = `td`.`id`  -- <= added `id` filter
        and `ti`.`shift` = `ts`.`shift`)
  ) as `t`
where `id` = 51;      -- <= now you can filter over its result
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4cd9/7)

---

**Update :**
As you changed your question again:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from (
      select a.Date 
      from (
          select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
          from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
          cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
          cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
      ) a
      where a.Date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-04'
       ) as `td`     -- gathering unique data
  cross join (
      select 1 `shift`
      union all select 2
      union all select 3) as `ts`  -- generating a source for shifts
  where not exists (
      select 1 from `yourTable` as `ti`
      -- filtering those are not exists in current rows
      where `ti`.`date` = `td`.`date` 
        and `ti`.`id` = 51
        and `ti`.`shift` = `ts`.`shift`)
  ) as `t`;
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4cd9/14)

Comment: Your question is unclear! it has many answers related to what are you expecting as result after adding that condition ;).

Comment: i want to add id in table and find according id condition

Comment: I suggest you ask it in another question; with providing some sample data - that has an id - and your expected result - that comes after adding that condition - HTH ;).

Comment: your query doesn't return result of  1st shift of `2017-01-01` it is also missing in 51 id

Comment: ANSWER IS CORRECT BUT IT IS NOT AS PER MY QUESTION.
please help me

Comment: I can't understand what is your expected result, please provide a better sample data and your expected result -HTH ;).

Comment: In this table also missing 1,2 and 3 shift of 2017-01-04 so i want to show that in result that 3 rows

Comment: SO, Do you have any table for a calendar?

Comment: no i don't have calendar, but i want to show result between min(date) and max(date) of that id

Comment: Please don't change your question, instead ask another question ;).

Comment: sorry next time i wont,
this time i dont have privilegges so

Comment: My last update will use a kind of in-line calendar -HTH ;).